# I have trouble to copy the string from buffer to a new array which contains strings (char *)

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to use `strcpy' to copy the strings in buffer to a new array that contains strings (char *). I always received error message of seg fault. But I don't know why that happen.

```c
char buffer[1024];
FILE *fp1;
fp1 = fopen("input.txt", "r");
char* array[file_row];
int index = 0;

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp1) != NULL) {
    strcpy(array[index++], buffer);
    printf("%s", buffer);
}

fclose(fp1);
return 0;
```

This is my part of codes, I hope that can provide enough information about my problem. I can't allocate memory for that array since its size is fixed, and I think I don't need to allocate each slot in array since `strcpy` did that for me. Also, I can print the content in buffer, so I think buffer worked well. Then I am not sure why this error happened. Can someone help me please?

Comment: By the way, `file_row` is the number of lines in `input.txt`. It's a part of my code, so I haven't shown that part. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THis

```
char* array[file_row];
```

is an array of pointers that point nowhere. In order to strcpy to them they have to point to a section of memory large enough to take the string. The easy solution is to use `strdup` it will allocate the memory and copy the string for you

instead of

```
  strcpy(array[index++], buffer);
```

do

```
  array[index++] = strdup(buffer);
```

(on windows you need `_strdup`)